# Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities, primitive-types

I am using LINQ to Entities and I am getting the following error at runtime. "Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types".

The LINQ statement look like:

```
(From item In _EntityObject.SystemUsers
 Where item.Username = UsernameValue And
     Not Equals(item.ID, IDValue)
 Select item.Active).Count
```

When IDValue is set to **Nothing**, the query executes perfectly while when I set the value to an **Integer** I'm getting the above error. **item.ID** is property of type Integer while **IDValue** is of type **Nullable(Of Integer)**.

I have the same LINQ query which different fields that I am using somewhere else which is working perfectly.

```
(From item In _EntityObject.Languages
 Where item.Reference = Reference And
     Not Equals(item.ID, ID)
 Select item.Name).Count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved with the below statement:

```
(From item In _EntityObject.SystemUsers Where 
item.Username = Username And (Not (item.ID = IDValue)
 Or IDValue Is Nothing) Select item.Name).Count)
```

Answer (score 1):

just use the `=` sign

```
(From item In _EntityObject.SystemUsers
 Where item.Username = UsernameValue And
     Not (item.ID = IDValue)
 Select item.Active).Count
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. However the value of IDValue can be Nothing (NULL) and this Equality comparism won't work.

Comment: in that case use (Not (m.CountryEnumId = IDValue)) Or (IDValue Is Nothing), but since your item.ID is never gonna be Nothing just omit the where clause part

Comment: Thanks for your help... You pointed me in the right direction. Actually the ID could be Nothing. Final query look like: `From item In _EntityObject.SystemUsers Where item.Username = Username And (Not (item.ID = IDValue) Or IDValue Is Nothing) Select item.Name).Count`